# AWS CloudWatchLog limit

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I am trying to find centralized solution to move my application logging from database (RDS).

I was thinking to use CloudWatchLog but noticed that there is a limit for PutLogEvents requests:

> The maximum rate of a PutLogEvents request is 5 requests per second
>   per log stream.

Even if I will break my logs into many streams (based on EC2, log type - error,info,warning,debug) the limit of 5 req. per second is still very restrictive for an active application.

The other solution is to somehow accumulate logs and send PutLogEvents with log records batch, but it means then I am forced to use database to accumulate that records.

So the questions is:

1. May be I'm wrong and limit of 5 req. per second is not so restrictive?
2. Is there any other solution that I should consider, for example DynamoDB?

Answer (score 3):

PutLogEvents is designed to put several events by definition (as per it name: PutLogEvent"S") :) Cloudwatch logs agent is doing this on its own and you don't have to worry about this.

However please note: I don't recommend you to generate to much logs (e.g don't run debug mode in prodution), as cloudwatch logs can become pretty expensive as your volume of log is growing.

Comment: Thanks for answer Tom, could you please clarify:
"Cloudwatch logs agent is doing this on its own and you don't have to worry about this."
I'm calling PutLogEvents directly from my application, is there any other way to send my application logs to CloudWatchLog?

Comment: Yes you can install the cloudwatch logs agent and specify which files you want to push to AWS. See documentation here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/fr_fr/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/QuickStartEC2Instance.html

Comment: I see, it means that I should log to a file (filesystem). Currently I'm looking for API call based (service) solution. Thanks for your input.

Comment: yes this is indeed file based, but it seems pretty easy to use a file along with an agent, instead of sending directly to cloudwatch. What benefits would you get from using PutLogEvents instead? do you have a specific use case requiring this? in this case you will have to buffer the logs to respect the limitation of 5 requests per seconds

Comment: Other solution I just thought about: send your events to an sqs queue instead of cloudwatch logs, and have either a lambda function or workers polling this queue to put the events in cloudwatch logs without crossing the limit

Comment: Thanks Tom, the idea with SQS is nice and worth to be investigated.

Answer (score 1):

If you are calling this API directly from your application: the short answer is that you need to batch you log events (it's 5 for PutLogEvent**s**).

If you are writing the logs to disk and after that you are pushing them there is already an agent that knows how to push the logs (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/QuickStartEC2Instance.html)

Meta: I would suggest that you prototype this and ensure that it works for the log volume that you have. Also, keep in mind that, because of how the cloudwatch api works, only one application/user can push to a log stream at a time (see the token you have to pass in) - so that you probably need to use multiple stream, one per user / maybe per log type to ensure that your applicaitions are not competing for the log.

Meta Meta: think about how your application behaves if the logging subsystem fails and if you can live with the possibility of losing the logs (ie is it critical for you to always/always have the guarantee that you will get the logs?). this will probably drive what you do / what solution you ultimately pick.

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be to use a Logstash solution on an AWS instance.

In alternative, you can run logstash on another existing instance or container.

https://www.elastic.co/products/logstash

It is designed for this scope and it does it wonderfully.

Cloudwatch, is not designed mainly for your needs.

I hope this helps somehow.

Comment: Thanks Maurizio, sure it helps, but I would prefer solution that doesn't require management from my side. Thanks again

Comment: I see what you mean.
Have you tried to have a look to this official amazon blog entry? 
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/cloudwatch-log-service/